# How to create or emulate nested lists needed for basic purchase order tracking

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list

I've been tasked with building a very simplistic Purchase Order entry and tracking system using SharePoint Foundation 2010. I know how tricky such things can be, and thus this is not an official system (we're using a cryptic backend system for the Real Deal, and I'd prefer to stay as far away from it as possible). However, we would like to at least have a basic end-user accessible system for the initial creation of POs and light tracking versus the paper forms we've been using up to this point.

The issue that I've run into is one of having a "list of lists": a PO would have top-level information (Date, Vendor, Requestor, and so forth) and then have one or more line items (Description, Cost, Quantity, etc). Viewing the list of POs would just show the top-level data (and maybe some totals and so forth) but one could drill down to view a specific PO's list of line items if one was so inclined.

I'm trying to come up with a decent approach to handling this, but I'm stumped and I don't have the vocabulary to aid me in searching for a suitable solution. I found [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5230/nested-table-in-list) previous question, but it doesn't exactly apply as far as I can tell.

That said, I appreciate any and all suggestions. For what it's worth, I'm thankful this forum is here, and I look forward to the day when I'm skilled enough to help others, though for now, I'm but an amateur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do Lists within Lists (that hierarchy is just not supported), but what you can do is use Lookup Columns to refer an item in one list to an item in another, and sorta re-create the story you're after.

On your last comment about being skilled enough one day? Just stick around, that's all there is. See how other people help each other, see what answers people put, and share your experiences when someone posts a problem that you might have come across!

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing that Infopath does very well, if you have the right licensing for it.

see [this comparison](https://web.archive.org/web/20151112162455/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/infopath/archive/2010/04/22/comparing-list-and-form-library-forms.aspx) for more information.